# How to get Activity child view in custom view class (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-custom-view, findviewbyid

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {

private Context context;
private ActionMode mActionmode;
private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback;
private SearchView searchView;


public CustomWebView(Context context){
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){

    super(context,attrs);
    this.context = context;
    WebSettings webSettings = this.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    this.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "JavaScriptInterface");


    this.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            if (mActionmode != null)
                return false;

            mActionmode = startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
            v.setSelected(true);
            return true;
        }
    });

    Log.w("test",context.toString());
    searchView =  ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.searchView);
}
```

I want to get searchview from activity (parent view of Customwebview).
But This code generates error message.

```
searchView =  ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.searchView);
```

I would like to call methods of searchView but it has null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to initialize searchview in activity and pass it to you customwebview 
add this to your customwebview class

```
Searchview searchview;
public void setSearchview(Searchview 
searchview){ this.searchview=searchvie
w}
// then call whatever functions you 
 want on searchview
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one more parameter in your constructor for SearchView

```
public CustomWebView(Context context, SearchView searchView){
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.searchView = searchView;
}
```